# Не работает script type=module

Tags: javascript, импорт, export, модули

Раньше я использовал модули в проектах node.js, никаких проблем с этим не было. Пришло время поэкспериментировать и попробовать использовать модули на чистом html/js, и тут я застрял.

Цитата из учебника:

> Так как модули поддерживают ряд специальных ключевых слов, и у них
> есть ряд особенностей, то необходимо явно сказать браузеру, что скрипт
> является модулем, при помощи атрибута `<script type="module">.`
>
> Браузер автоматически загрузит и запустит импортированный модуль (и
> те, которые он импортирует, если надо), а затем запустит скрипт.

Вооружившись этими знаниями, создаем файлы sayHi.js и script.js;

```
// sayHi.js
export function sayHi(user) {
  alert(`Hello, ${user}!`);
}

// script.js
import {sayHi} from './sayHi.js';
sayHi('John'); // Hello, John!
```

И в index.html в конце body прописываем type в теге script:

```
<script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
```

В результате консоль показывает ошибку:

> GET http://localhost:63342/HTML%20CSS/sayHi net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not
> Found)

То есть, получается, JS не видит файл sayHi. Что я сделал не так?

Comment: Он же запросил файл по адресу, но сервер его не отдал. Либо файла там нет, либо сервер не хочет отдавать))

Comment: `<script type="module" src="sayHi.js"></script>`

Comment: @Leonid  спасибо, кэп. Что делать-то?

Comment: Выше уже написали, видимо надо и этот файл также добавить как модуль. А уже взаимоотношение между ними будет регулироваться инструкциями `export-import`. Как минимум вариант, наверное. Проверьте отдает ли сервер файл по этому адресу.

Comment: @Leonid Это не работает. "Загрузка модуля по адресу «http://localhost:63342/HTML%20CSS/sayHi» была заблокирована из-за неразрешенного MIME-типа («text/html»)". Добавление <meta content="text/plain"> тоже не помогает.

Comment: Покажите структуру файлов, перенесите script в конец head (модуль всегда выполняется после загрузки dom), и добавьте полный код html страницы

Comment: `text/javascript` или `application/javascript` должен быть, насколько я знаю. При чем тут вообще `text/html`? Просто если в адресную строку вбить localhost:63342/HTML%20CSS/sayHi, то сервер что отдает? И почему разрешилось `sayHi.js` в `sayHi` как если бы это была директория, как ваш сервер разрешает (преобразовывает) адреса?